# Follow Unfollow system

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on this site that follow and unfollow users just like Twitter follow.
The query below works then I notice it doesn't show me users I don't follow because the user has been followed by somebody or is following somebody

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM town_users LEFT JOIN user_follow_list ON user_follow_list.following_id = town_users.user_id WHERE town_users.user_id != ? AND user_follow_list.follow_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
```

Below is my table structure

```
town_users
user_id username
| 1    | ben
| 2    | betty
| 3    | tom
| 4    | john


user_follow_list
follow_id         follower_id         following_id
|      1     |       1         |      2
|      2     |       1         |      3
```

In the user_follow_list `Ben` is following `betty` and `tom`. Now `john` follows a user let say `tom`,

```
follow_id         follower_id         following_id
|      3     |       4         |      3
```

Now the problem am having is that `john` doesn't show up on `ben` list of users to follow.

It's meant to show users I haven't followed so I can follow them.

Comment: What is the idea of making `user_follow_list.follow_id IS NULL` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. without the user_follow_list.follow_id IS NULL it will keep on showing me users i have followed

Comment: use a SELECT CASE on following_id

Comment: okay will look into that but the truth is am just a beginner. Maybe you can help me rewrite that. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Everythinggood Have you tried something like 
`AND user_follow_list.follower_id != :user_id` instead of it?

Comment: Thanks @xTrimy but its not working showing blank

Comment: I tried it and worked for me. Make sure to bind the :user_id

Comment: Try this full code. `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM town_users LEFT JOIN user_follow_list ON user_follow_list.following_id = town_users.user_id WHERE town_users.user_id != :user_id AND user_follow_list.follower_id != :user_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");` Then `$stmt->bind_param(":user_id", $user_id);`

Comment: I will try to write a simplified query as an answer

Comment: I tried doing it your way didnt work. i will send you a sqlfiddle. I really appreciate your effort

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, I was confused by the follower and following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM town_users 
LEFT JOIN user_follow_list ON user_follow_list.follower_id = town_users.user_id 
WHERE town_users.user_id NOT IN (SELECT following_id FROM user_follow_list WHERE 
follower_id = 1) AND town_users.user_id != 1
GROUP BY town_users.user_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

This query will get all the user that are not being followed by (`$user_id = 1`).

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM town_users 
                          LEFT JOIN user_follow_list ON user_follow_list.follower_id = town_users.user_id 
                          WHERE town_users.user_id NOT IN (SELECT following_id FROM user_follow_list WHERE follower_id = ?) 
                          AND town_users.user_id != ?
                          GROUP BY town_users.user_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $user_id);
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96d55/23/0